# Optimize nested enumerate blocks?

Tags: performance, array, objective-c

I have 3 nested `NSEnumeration` loops, which are used to get the textfields of a custom cell, in a custom table in a custom view in a controller.

How can I make this code more readable and more optimizated?

```
- (void) textfieldsOperations:(APOperation)op
{
  __block int Valid = 0;
  __block NSArray *sub = _Table.subviews;
  __block MyCell *cell = nil;
  __block UIView *view = nil;
  __block NSMutableArray *ret = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:5];

  [sub enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id c, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)
  {
    if ( [c isKindOfClass:[MyCell class]] ) {
      cell = c;
      [cell.subviews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id v, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)
      {
        if ( [v isKindOfClass:[UIView class]] ) {
          view = v;
          [view.subviews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id t, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)
          {
            if ( [t isKindOfClass:[MyTextField class]] )
            {
              MyTextField *txt = t;
              switch ( op )
              {
                case APOperationClear:
                  // something with "txt"
                  break;
                case APOperationEnableSearch:
                  // something with "valid"
                  break;
                case APOperationGetText:
                  // something with "txt"
                  break;
                case APOperationPos: {
                  // something with "txt"
                  break;
                }
              }
            }
          }];
        }
      }];
    }
  }];
  //[...]      
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

honestly: this code should be replaced completely.

you dont give any informations about how your MyCell and MyTextField look like, so I can just give you a general advice: Let MyTextField have a delegate it can call if a certain operation is triggered on it.

ie it could call  `textField:(MyTextField *)textField didTriggerOperation:(APOperation)op` and the implementation would be similar to:

```
-(void)textField:(MyTextField *)textField didTriggerOperation:(APOperation)op
{
    if(textField == self.descriptionTextField){
        if(op){
            switch ( op )
            {
              case APOperationClear:
                // something with "txt"
                break;
              case APOperationEnableSearch:
                // something with "valid"
                break;
              case APOperationGetText:
                // something with "txt"
                break;
              case APOperationPos: {
                // something with "txt"
                break;
              }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

your textField would call is when the operation was triggered like

```
[self.delegate textField:self didTriggerOperation:operation];
```